# Problems deploying firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use firebase functions in reactjs to create a trigger that sends a mail when information is uploaded to the firestore database.

A bridge is created with nodemailer and a function is executed when a new document is loaded into the db.

This is the code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
/* const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(); */

// GmailAccount
const gmailUser = "myname@gmail.com"; //example mail, use another
const gmailPassword = "mypass"; //example pass, it is not the real one that I use.

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: gmailUser,
    pass: gmailPassword
  }
});
exports.newContact = functions.firestore
  .document("/Contacts/{documentId}")
  .onCreate((snap, contentxt) => {
    const name = snap.data().name;
    return sendEmail(name);
  });

const sendEmail = (name) => {
  return transport
    .sendMail({
      from: gmailUser,
      to: "myEmail@gmail.com",
      subject: "test",
      html:name
    })
    .then(r => console.log(r))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

So far so good. The problem occurs when I want to deploy: I execute the command:

`firebase deploy --only functions` and the console gives me the following:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        newContact(us-central1)
i functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

A more detailed error would be the following:

```
{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code.
```

When running: `firebase emulators:start --only functions`

It tells me: `function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running`

Comment: Where is `transportation` declared? It's just `transport`. Also can you try using `sendMail` directly in the Cloud function is renaming the var doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, it's ```transport``` instead of ```transportation```, but it still doesn't work. I've also tried moving ```sendEmail ``` around and it doesn't work either.